# Interpreting % residuals

Tags: residuals

Is there an acceptable range for %residuals value?  When looking at %residuals from calibration curve is there an acceptance criteria for the values?

Comment: What do you mean by the "%residuals value"?

Answer (score 4):

Suppose that your task is to predict people's height, and the predictors you are given are sex and nationality. Then your predictions won't be very accurate, so the residuals will be high. But you might have made the best model possible given the data available.

Is this acceptable? Well, to whom and for what purpose? If you are implementing a clothing website, and your model is used to suggest the default among small, medium, and large, then you model might be good enough.

If your model is used to decide the dose of a pharmaceutical, then the acceptable error depends on the margin between the therapeutic dose and the toxic dose, which is large for a statin, but surprisingly small for acetominophen (paracetamol/tylenol).

Models have errors. Errors have consequences. Unless your model is purely an academic exercise, the question is always: what is the cost of the errors?